# XLSWriter - format columns from list

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am creating an excel from a dataframe.  The output of excel has 1300 columns.  Certain columns need to be date format in excel (already datetime format in dataframe).  Those columns have the word "Time" in the header.

Sample of 3 columns of data:

```
Dyn_10     Dyn_Price_10     Dyn_Time_10
-2             0.9493       44026.90764
-5             0.9625       44034.65486
0              0.9535       44035.67569
-10            0.9535       44035.67569
```

My existing code finds out the column numbers with Time in them and then iterates through the columns from the TimesColsNum list and sets the format::

```
TimeCols = np.core.defchararray.find(CombinedDFDict[s].columns.values.astype(str), 'Time') >= 0
TimeColsNum = [i for i, x in enumerate(TimeCols) if x]
for t in TimeColsNum:
     wss.set_column(t, 20, date_format)
wb.close()
```

The problem is I get an error.  I remove these two lines of code, and there is no error.

```
for t in TimeColsNum:
     wss.set_column(t, 20, date_format)
```

I don't know what to do. I appreciate any and all guidance.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Path\DynamicExitComparisonsv6.py", line 815, in <module>
    wb.close()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 320, in close
    self._store_workbook()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 685, in _store_workbook
    xml_files = packager._create_package()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 135, in _create_package
    self._write_worksheet_files()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 190, in _write_worksheet_files
    worksheet._assemble_xml_file()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 3871, in _assemble_xml_file
    self._write_cols()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 5416, in _write_cols
    self._write_col_info(self.colinfo[col])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 5445, in _write_col_info
    if width > 0:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Format' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of XlsxWriter [`worksheet.set_column()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-column) is:

```py
set_column(first_col, last_col, width, cell_format, options)
```

In your example you are only setting one of the columns. Try this instead:

```py
wss.set_column(t, t, 20, date_format)
```